# From which anime is this ad on Scifi SE?

Tags: naruto

Here is the image that appeared in [this ad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/community-promotion-ads-2013#2535) on Scifi SE.

[image: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/community-promotion-ads-2013#2535]

What anime is the character in this image from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The anime is Naruto and the character is Itachi Uchiha.

[image]